# Entity Framework - IsRequired() vs. OnDelete()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to understand relationships in EF Core using Fluent API. I am coming from a background of using Attribute notation.

What is the guidance around using:

`IsRequired()` and `OnDelete()`.

Are they interchangeable or do they conflict with each other? Can I use just one of these methods to achieve my goals?

As I understand it, the `OnDelete()` method is more extensive but can I only use it instead of `IsRequired()` in all cases?

i.e.: Here I can't use `true` in `IsRequired()` when using `SetNull`, but if I comment out the `IsRequired()` line then everything works:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
      .HasOne(b => b.Biography)
      .WithOne(u => u.User)
      .HasForeignKey<Biography>(u => u.UserId)
      .IsRequired(false)
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

If I'm wrong please give examples where `IsRequired()` is mandatory and only `OnDelete()` does not helps.

Comment: `OnDelete` and `IsRequired` have very different use cases and mean a different thing - you can have a nullable foreign key which still has "on delete behavior"

Comment: I'm trying to anderstand relationships using Fluent API, anotations are much easy for me.
as I know `.IsRequired(true)` makes the FK required (which by default will turn cascade delete on).

Comment: @nbokmans but why they conflict?

Comment: Are you familiar with relational database design fundamentals and theory? I'm curious if you're able to separate EF's features and functionality away from the meat-and-potatoes of database design...

Comment: @DevMis there are no "required" vs "non-required" foreign key *constraints* in a database. An FK is a constraint, not a relation. The Relation is the *table* itself - it defines a relation between its values. ORMs try to give the impression of working with in-memory object instead of tables though, so they use Object-Oriented terms. It's purely an ORM convention that rows are translated to objects and FK constraints to relations/properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IsRequired()` and `OnDelete()` have an affect on each other but are not strictly *interchangable*. There are 7 different `DeleteBehaviour` values and only 2 states of `IsRequired`, so only 2 states are configured by default conventions depending on the value passed into `IsRequired(bool)`.

- Use of `IsRequired()` is not mandatory at all, if omitted it is inferred by the *nullability* of the type of the associated property. If the property is a *nullable*, then `IsRequired(false)` is implied, otherwise `IsRequired(true)` is implied.

If your use case matches the default conventions, then you do not need to specify `IsRequired()` and `OnDelete()` together at all. You might still choose to do so to make your intent explicit, however the concept of conventions was added so that you could make global decisions in one place and reduce the references to rules like this in your code that become a lot harder to maintain.

So how does this affect `OnDelete()`?

> **See [DeleteBehaviour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-7.0)**
> `Cascade`
> Automatically deletes dependent entities when the principal is deleted or the relationship to the principal is severed, and creates creates a foreign key constraint in the database with cascading deletes enabled. ***This is the default for required relationships.***
>
> `ClientSetNull`
> Sets foreign key values to null as appropriate when changes are made to tracked entities, and creates a non-cascading foreign key constraint in the database. This is the default for optional relationships.

By the default conventions in EF (that you can override) when a FK is marked as *required* via `IsRequired(true)` then cascade delete will be the default behaviour on delete of the related principal record.

- You cannot use `IsRequired(true)` and `DeleteBehaviour.SetNull` because that doesn't make sense, the first statement says that `null` is not allowed, the second tries to force `null` values to be assigned.

If you choose to make the FK optional via `IsRequired(false)` then the default `OnDelete()` is `DeleteBehaviour.ClientSetNull`. This means that only the loaded entities in the context before the delete will have their FKs set to null when the principal entity is deleted. If there are other records in the database that reference that same FK value, when you try to save changes, it will fail due to a database reference constraint violation.

If you want the database to proactively set the FK for all other records in the database that reference the same FK value then we *MUST* specify `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)` to add a constraint to the database that will execute this cleanup logic.

`IsRequired(bool)` is generally not required in conjunction with `OnDelete()`, but this is only due to your intelligent setting of the nullability on the FK property. If you are using a shadow property for the FK, then `IsRequired()`  really is *required*, but otherwise the standard convention is to use the nullability of the FK.